# How to clear back stack of Multiple Navigation graph in android?

Tags: android, navigation

I have implemented the multiple nav graph using bottom navigation like below.
[image]

What is happening here is when i go to `page number 1` on `homeFragment` and then navigate to `dashboard` through bottom navigation after that when i return to `home` it opens `page number 1` on `homeFragment`.

Instead, I want to do is when coming to `homeFragment` from `dashboard` or `notification` then starting fragment will open not `page number 1`

Answer (score 0):

you can use [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-navigate#pop-example) for explicit pop or [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-navigate#back-stack) general pop can be used as well.(Also, make sure that you do not open page number1 manually.try to implement that with navigation components. )

Comment: I am asking about clearing the stack for a particular navHost

Comment: you can do that byu overriding the onback pressed on the  activity and implement your logic with popUpTo and popUpToInclusive attributes (from first link). Just use another action for back press state.

Answer (score 0):

Check your menu.xml and remove below from menu items

`android:menuCategory="secondary"`